# Installing Intel N7260 driver in Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

Hello I am installing Debian Buster on my Panasonic Toughbook CF-53 MK. 4

While setting it up I've been having issues getting the wireless card to work, even though it works on Ubuntu. I know the ethos on why Debian does this.

I believe my driver is an N7260. Which is a UDev script which is reccomended to install via

`cp iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode /lib/firmware`

I've performed the above, but how do I enable the driver? Rebooting doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,
Moose

Comment: firmware-iwlwifi  https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-iwlwifi  →  Intel Wireless 7260 firmware

Comment: Type "lsmod | grep iwl" to see if the firmware-iwlwifi" as install correctly, and  type "dmesg | grep iwl" to check for errors.Also, I suggest you use "apt install firmware-iwlwifi" to install the firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe my driver is an N7260. Which is a UDev script which is reccomended to install via ...

You might need the **contrib** and **non-free** channels in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  If you installed Debian without the the [nonfree firmware iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/), I would recommend adding the `contrib` and `non-free` channels in your apt configuration rather than trying to download and install it manually.

This provides a couple advantages:

- By installing the driver with `apt`, you don't need to worry about setting up the configuration yourself.
- Your driver will get updates automatically.
- You're not going to accidentally bork your system.